# MOOG 2019 and gfortran

Tags: spectroscopy, software

I've been trying to install MOOG Nov2019 ([utexas](http://www.as.utexas.edu/%7Echris/moog.html), [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moog_(code))) on my desktop running OpenSUSE 13.1. I have the SM and X11 library paths copied into the makefile, and I am *3-sigma confident* that they are the correct pathways. I'm using cc as the C compiler, and gfortan for Fortran. When I run the makefile, I get a string of errors that looks like this:

```
gfortran -Wall -g -std=legacy Abfind.o Abpop.o Abunplot.o Batom.o Begin.o Binary.o Binplot.o Binplotprep.o Blankstring.o Blends.o Bmolec.o Boxit.o Calmod.o Cdcalc.o Chabund.o Cog.o Cogplot.o Cogsyn.o Correl.o Crosscorr.o Curve.o Damping.o Defcolor.o Discov.o Doflux.o Drawcurs.o Eqlib.o Ewfind.o Ewweighted.o Fakeline.o Findtic.o Finish.o Fluxplot.o Gammabark.o Getasci.o Getcount.o Getnum.o Getsyns.o Gridplo.o Gridsyn.o Infile.o Inlines.o Inmodel.o Invert.o Jexpint.o Lineinfo.o Lineabund.o Linlimit.o Makeplot.o Molquery.o Moog.o Mydriver.o Nansi.o Nearly.o Number.o Obshead.o Oneline.o Opaccouls.o OpacHelium.o OpacHydrogen.o Opacit.o Opacmetals.o Opacscat.o Params.o Partfn.o Partnew.o Plotit.o Plotremember.o Pltabun.o Pltcog.o Pltflux.o Pltspec.o Pointcurs.o Prinfo.o Putasci.o Readobs.o Rinteg.o Setmols.o Smooth.o Specplot.o Stats.o Sunder.o Synpop.o Synspec.o Synth.o Tablepop.o Taukap.o Total.o Trudamp.o Ucalc.o Vargauss.o Vmacro.o Voigt.o Wavecalc.o Weedout.o Writenumber.o -o MOOG -L/usr/local/lib/X11  -lX11 \
        -L/usr/local/pkg/sm/2.4.36-F90/lib -lplotsub -ldevices -lutils

Abunplot.o: In function `abunplot_':
Abunplot.f:(.text+0x624): undefined reference to `sm_defvar__'
Abunplot.f:(.text+0x64e): undefined reference to `sm_window__'
Abunplot.f:(.text+0x66c): undefined reference to `sm_limits__'
Abunplot.f:(.text+0x6c6): undefined reference to `sm_ticksize__'
.
.
.
```

Running the nm command in the sm library yields:

```
> nm /usr/local/pkg/sm/2.4.36-F90/lib/libplotsub.a | grep ylabel
0000000000001cc6 T sm_ylabel
                 U sm_ylabel
0000000000000dae T sm_ylabel_
                 U sm_ylabel
```

Based on the readme for MOOGStokes (https://www2.mpia-hd.mpg.de/homes/deen/Software/MoogStokes/MoogStokes.README.txt), it looks like this error arises from how gfortran and SM handle underscores. I've tried using the gfortran flags listed in the MOOGStokes readme, but the problem persists. Are there other flags I should use, or is there another way to resolve this?

Comment: MOOG obviously has dependencies. Have you satisfied those dependencies>

Comment: Try adding `-fno-second-underscore` to the gfortran compile flags

Comment: @astrosnapper  - No luck including that flag.

Comment: @DavidHammen - Which dependencies are you referring to?

Comment: @uhoh Yes! Sorry, I had gotten caught up in other work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SM developers seem to have [anticipated](https://www.astro.princeton.edu/%7Erhl/sm/sm.html#SEC51) such issues.
In your `nm` output sample,

`T sm_ylabel` is the native C function, and

`T sm_ylabel_` is its wrapper to be called from Fortran.

`gfortran` usually appends single underscores to external symbol names.
If the MOOG object files were in fact built with the `gfortran` options in the question, the symbol references should match the wrappers in the SM library.
The double underscore suffixes may be left over from a prior build attempt with `-ff2c`.
When you change compiler options, remember to `make clean` before rebuilding.

If that doesn't lead to a solution, and nothing else is using SM,
the SM manual [suggests](https://www.astro.princeton.edu/%7Erhl/sm/sm.html#SEC57)
that you could rebuild it with this in its `options.h`:

```
#define FORTRAN_APPEND __
```

Comment: Thanks! Cleaning and recompiling did the trick!